# Wait for Matlab "system" function to finish before continuing script execution

Tags: matlab, system

I'm running a Matlab script on windows 10, which in turns calls a shell script file in order to run some simulations on Ubuntu using bash.
By definition the Matlab "system" function waits for the .sh file to finish before continuing the executation of the Matlab script. The problem arises when the .sh function calls a subprocess, because in that case Matlab doesn't wait for this subprocess to finish and continues the execution of the Matlab script.
Does somebody knows how to force Matlab to wait for the total completion of the .sh script before continuing execution?

Comment: I don't think you can, as this is controlled outside MATLAB, its an OS thing. Unless you can make that subprocess signal MATLAB....

Comment: The shell script shouldn't finish until subprocesses have finished, unless you start them asynchronously (with the & at the end). But one workaround is to have MATLAB wait for the result file to be written. Just try to open the file, if it is not there, wait a second, and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

insert this before and after the system(CodeName)

```
if exist(RelutFileName, 'file')==2; delete (RelutFileName); end

system(CodeName);

while exist(RelutFileName, 'file')~=2; pause(1); end
```

Comment: Can you explain what it does?